# Can you find the length of a pencil without a ruler or clock?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, thought-experiment

**Edit**: Assume you do have access to all sorts of instruments, but they are all shrunk in proportion. My real question is:

> If you are shrunken (or expanded) by a constant factor and put in a room shrunken by that constant factor, can you be fooled into thinking you are in a regular-size world, by altering your time perception by a constant factor?

Suppose a magic fairy comes up to you, and transports you into some opaque box. You are given a potion that alters your time perception, and changes the size of your body.

Assume that the effects of the potion are constant: each second feels like $x$ seconds, and your height has been multiplied by a factor of $y$. You do not know the values of $x$ and $y$.

Helpfully, the fairy has left you a suitably shrunken/expanded copy of a textbook, listing basically every single constant and formula in physics. Unfortunately for you, all the dimensionful constants are measured in SI units.

There is no clock or ruler in sight. You *can* measure the ratios of sizes or time intervals because the potion doesn't have variable effects.

The fairy gives you a pencil, and says that once you tell him how long the pencil is, in **centimeters**, you are released.

There are some ways to do this task of course. The ones I thought of involve building a microscope and attempting to eyeball the radius of, say, a carbon-12 atom, and then multiplying that by the ratio between the radius of a carbon-12 atom and a meter, found in the textbook. However, this is close to impossible to do. We might be able to try to diffract light to measure objects in multiples of, say, the wavelength of 500 nm green light.

However, neither of these methods are particularly accurate or useful. Besides, without any measurement equipment we can't be sure of the wavelength of the light. Would there be some obvious, classical way of deriving the length of a meter without access to any ruler?

Comment: With no point of reference I'm not sure how anything can be measured. Though I suppose there are limits at which certain biological compounds - hair, hemoglobin, etc. - could not form, and so, if you're alive, you can assume you're larger than those. But I'm not sure how you can set an upper limit of size on a magic box.

Comment: How high can you jump?

Comment: You build a simple gas discharge lamp for a known atomic transition (helium, sodium etc. will do) and then you count interference fringes on a simple interferometer to get a length standard.

Comment: @CuriousOne How do you measure the distance between your 2 interference holes ? The distance between fringes is function of the distance between the holes... :p

Comment: @TheNaturalTanuki: I am using an interferometer with a movable mirror. The fairy didn't take my mirrors away, did she?

Comment: @CuriousOne Genuine question: In this case how do you measure the path length difference ?

Comment: @TheNaturalTanuki: You don't. Your atomic transitions tables tell you the wavelength and then you just count fringes.

Comment: @CuriousOne The number of fringes is function of the wavelength and the path length difference. If you have a ruler to measure the path length difference, you might as well use the ruler to measure 1 meter.

Comment: I don't have a ruler, but I know how long a fringe is.

Comment: Write with the pencil until it's worn completely out, then tell the fairy your pencil is 0 centimeters.

Comment: Is the box on the surface of the Earth?

Comment: I have edited the question title, because it appears to be what this question boils down to.

Comment: Doesn't this all depend on how perfect the transformations are? If the atoms are shrunk, then so are the wavelengths of their transitions, and so are the cone cells of your eyes, so the light wavelength is as meaningless as anything.

Comment: Wikipedia says: "A standard, #2, hexagonal pencil is 19 cm (7.5 in) long." You can start guessing from that, if the pencil is unsharpened.

Comment: Why would it be a standard pencil? The whole idea is to be deceptive.

Comment: @Random832 I believe the only thing that is shrunk is you. If not, the question needs rewriting.

Comment: @RobJeffries: Instruments etc are shrunken, but not atoms or cells etc. Basically, you are given objects *built* to be of different size, and *drugged* to perceive time differently, not put in a place where spacetime is shrunken. The "you are shrinked too" part is just to prevent cheating by using yourself as a ruler.

Comment: @user54609 That is what *I* have assumed.

Comment: `"The fairy gives you a pencil, and says that once you tell **him** how long the pencil is, in centimeters, you are released."` :o I always thought about fairies as female characters. Good that word "pencil" is not in quotation marks XD.

Comment: @Random832: I do not think it is possible for the whole universe to be shrunk in all aspects without altering some fundamental properties.

Comment: Read about the [Foucault Gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau%E2%80%93Foucault_apparatus) used to measure the speed of light in absolute terms.

Answer (score 11):

OK, time to burn thru all my mod points:

```
for (j  in 0:1e6 cm,by=1Angstrom) {
    print("Hi, magic fairy, the pencil is" ,j, "cm long")
}
```

Sooner or later you'll get it right and off you go.
(With apologies to the world-famous "If you tell me the height of the building I'll give you this barometer" story)

EDIT: for those who never ran across it, the "barometer" story is an example of lateral thinking in the classroom.  I'm sure it's apocryphal.  Here goes:

Teacher finishes explaining to a Physics class about variation of air pressure with altitude and then asks 'How can you use a barometer to find the height of a tall building?"  Well, you *could* try to measure the variation in barometric pressure and dig up enough reference data to guesstimate the altitude, or you could
1) drop the barometer off the top and, knowing gravitational force, use the measurement of elapsed time to estimate the distance travelled,
2) knock on the door of the building supervisor and say "I'll give you this really nice barometer if you'll tell me from the construction plans how tall the building is."
3) [fill in your own]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the "barometer" story; could you provide a link to it?

Comment: @IQAndreas dunno if it's online, but I'll put a brief version in my answer.

Comment: Hilarious story! I did find it on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question

Answer (score 10):

> transports you into some opaque box.

We are in a box, therefore we don't have additional measuring devices such as dynamometers or electrometers.

> each second feels like x seconds, and your height has been multiplied
>   by a factor of y. You do not know the values of x and y.

We can measure length and duration accurately albeit scaled. (For narrative purposes: use the pencil as a ruler, and count (1 Mississippi 2 Mississippi ) as a chronometer.)

### Method

Drop the pencil from some height. At some point, Measure its velocity, the height it traveled, and duration since you dropped it.

You have

$v_0 (ym / xs) = g * t_0 (xs)$

and

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 (ym / xs)^2 = g h_0 (ym)$

solve for y and use it to give pencil length.

### EDIT

After all your galilean experiments, you can only measure g in $pencil/Mississippi^2$, which gives you just $y/x^2$.

**Cop out:** Measure pencil's length while it moves at constant velocity. Solve for $c$ using length contraction formula $L=L_{0}\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}$. Which gives you $y/x$. Now, solve for $y$, (for real this time).

Comment: Unlike me, you read the question correctly... +1

Comment: Can you give an example of how this works with actual numbers? Does this imply that if you were shrinked by a magical potion and placed in a miniature room, no time-altering potion could fool you into thinking you were in an unshrinked room?

Comment: I don't think this works as stated. If $vy/x=gtx$, then $y=gt x^2 /v$. From the second eqn $x^2 =0.5v^2 y/gh$, so this gets you nowhere, unless I'm having a major post-Christmas brain-freeze.

Comment: @TheNaturalTanuki I interpreted the question differently.

Comment: @RobJeffries you're right. I'd written $$x s^2$$ instead of $$(x s)^2$$ in my calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all laws of physics are the same in this magical new world, and taking you at your word that everything is exactly proportional (so an atom would be larger/smaller depending on your new universe), a meter would still be defined as "the length of the path traveled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299 792 458 of a second".  So, a centimeter "there" is just like a centimeter "here".  Figure out the dimensions of your book, or find some scale inside of the book, and measure the pencil as normal.

Comment: But you don't have access to a clock.

Comment: His question is different than his title.  In his question he allows for measurement of time intervals.  At any rate, the point is not to make a measurement, it is to compare that "realm" to our own...which of course you cannot do.  I simply proposed that if all of the rules are the same as our realm, then any simple method of measuring a centimeter here would be like measuring a centimeter there.

Comment: I understand what you did now. Where I differed in the reasoning is that I assumed I could not rely on the book being written in the scaled world, but being taken from our world and scaled so that the person in the trap cannot infer the size of the pencil from the 'real world' size of the book.

Comment: I don't understand this solution. The book has been changed in size, so how do you "figure out the dimensions of your book"? There cannot be a scale inside of the book, otherwise that would count as a ruler.

Comment: Right, the book has changed in size, so have you, so have the atoms that compose your body and the book.  Hence, without a given relationship between our realm and that realm, you *cannot* compare the two.  Because both "realms" are indistinguishable from each other...they can both be treated as the same.  Therefore, 1 cm here = 1 cm there, no matter what clever method you use to measure 1 cm.

Comment: P.S. the title is different from the question.  The title question is impossible, as the only way to measure space is in using some predefined measure of distance...i.e. a ruler.  Now, in one of the other answers the poster uses Coulombs Law...but you can't have Coulombs Law unless you used a ruler at some point, so regardless, a ruler must have been used at some point to define the length of a meter, centimeter or whichever units you please.

Comment: I don't think you can assume that you and the book have been changed by the same factor. Even if you could, how do you "figure out the dimensions of your book"? This is the same problem as estimating the size of the pencil.

Comment: According to the prompt, that is exactly what you should be assuming.  And, who cares if you can't figure out the dimensions in the book, can't figure out the length of a standard pencil, can't find some 'to scale' drawing in the book etc.  The point is ***not*** that you make a measurement, the point is that whenever you measure your pencil in the other realm, it will be the exact same size as it is in our realm.

Comment: Just to be silly, the title says no rulers...so you could just tell the fairy she isn't the boss of you and to let you go!  Lol...

Answer (score 2):

Strip out the graphite from the pencil and make an estimate of the diameter of the "lead" compared to the length of the pencil. e.g. If the pencil is height $n$ metres, and the pencil "lead" has a diameter of, say, $n/100$, then the volume of graphite you have is $V = \pi n^3/400$. Weigh the graphite and this tells you what mass of graphite you have and then use the known density of graphite to tell you what $V$ and hence $n$ is.

How accurate you would be depends on how well you can measure how many pencil "lead" diameters make up the height of the pencil.

In terms of whether you could be fooled into not realising your size had changed; there is a simple test.

You didn't say whether the transformation you proposed was mass conserving. If it were, then you should weigh the same, but be $y^{-3}$ times denser than you were (assuming it wasn't just your height that was altered!). If $y<1$, then you would not be able to float. If $y>1$ then you would float abnormally well.

If the process somehow modified your mass to keep your density the same, then the simple act of weighing yourself would reveal the value of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition to not have access to a ruler or a clock is actually not very restrictive.

Use 2 electrons and use a very precise forcemeter.

$$F = k\frac{q_aq_b}{r^2}$$

Measure F and use the formula to deduce r, the distance between the 2 electrons.

Put one electron at each end of the pencil to answer the riddle.

Now if your question is can we determine a one meter distance without making any kind of measurement, I don't have the answer.

EDIT: here's a force-meter

[image]

Comment: What are you using to measure a force? Force is defined trough the acceleration of a mass. You need a ruler and a clock to measure acceleration...

Comment: Let me edit to include which instrument I am using.

Comment: Good luck measuring the force between two electrons with a force gauge. You could, of course, measure the force between some 1e14 electrons or so... it would be on the order of 1N. Now all you need to do, is to count 1e14 electrons. I think I stick to counting 10,000 fringes. :-)

Comment: What happens to the force-meter when you shrink it? i.e. assume that the component parts, e.g. the spring and the marked scale, are shrunk down, and behave in a way that the person holding it cannot tell the difference.

Comment: The idea of using a macroscopic force meter to measure the repulsion between two electrons is just too funny to not upvote this. +1

Comment: How can you use a force meter? Assume that the force meter is, too, shrinked in proportion.

Comment: It's the size of the force that is the issue, not the size of the force-meter!

Comment: @RobJeffries: The scale on the meter is shrunken too. I guess my question is actually "how to measure lengths when all the scales are shrunken in proportion"

Comment: @user54609 What does it matter how big the scale is? I think you don't know what your question is. Just because you make an instrument smaller, doesn't mean it measures wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the statements more carefully, I have deviced a method to determine the "real length" of a pencil (stick). If I can determine the values of the y (length) and x (time) factors, it will be simple to determine the pencil's length. In order to determine the y & x values, the following information is assumed/given: $g_1 = g_2 = g = 9.8 m/s^2$ ; $c_1 = c_2 = c$
I, and everything in the room **shrunk by y = 1/2.**
My thumb width tw, defined as 2cm long.

**Solution:**  find out the shrink factor and thereby be able to find the length of the pencil.

**Method:** create a "pendulum clock" who's period is 1 second (local time).  The length of a string for such pendulum is given by $L_2 = \frac{g{t_2}^2}{4{\pi}^2}$. For $T_2$ = 1 second, $L_2 = 24.85cm$. Using my thumb, I measure the string and create a "pendulum clock". Keep in mind that since I am shrunk by 1/2, $L_2$'s "real" length ($L_1$) is $\frac{L_2}{2}$, or 12.42cm.  So,outside my shrunk room, this pendulum would have a period of $T_1 = 2 \pi$ $(\frac{L_1}{g})^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2^{1/2}}sec$. Using a fiber optic cable of length (d) of 3 x 10^10; an LED; and a light detector; the time delay should be $t_2$ = d/c = 1sec.  However, the "real time" $t_1$ is = d/2c = 1/2 sec (since the real length is d/2), but since I am measuring time with my pendulum, then the pendulum period ($T_2$) required is $\frac{1/2}{\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}}$ = $\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}$. What must I do now to the string length so the pendulum's period is $\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}$ sec (instead of 1 sec)?  I have to multiply its **period** by $\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}$, which means **its length** must be multiplied by 1/2, thus **factor y = 1/2**. So now, if you give me a stick that's 20cm long, I will determine it's 40cm long, but because I know the shrink factor is 1/2, I can say that the length of the stick is **really** 20cm.

Comment: The whole point about shrinking *you* by a factor y is so that you cannot do this. The pencil could be changed by any amount or not at all.

Comment: It appears I was confused by the various statements into believing that everything was affected the same by the "shrink/expand" factor. With your comment, it is now clear I don't understand the question/problem, since it introduces a third "z" unknown factor for the pencil, which I had not even considered.

Comment: After reviewing the problem statements I came up with a new approach.  I think this time I used the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

A low-tech solution

Assuming that you're near or on the surface of the Earth, you construct a pendulum (of unknown length). Then determine the oscillation frequency, using your pulse as a time base. You can then determine the length of the pendulum, which you use as a ruler to calibrate all other lengths.

Your pulse isn't very accurate as a clock, but I would guesstimate that you can get the length better than 10%. Hopefully the fairy isn't too picky.

Answer (score 0):

**They do it with mirrors**

Take an [interferometer](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/what-is-interferometer) set up using a laser and where you can vary the distance between one mirror and the beam splitter.

By knowing how far you have gone between two points where the light was fully destructively interfering you can know the distance in the number of wavelengths.

Then you just put the pencil lined up with the mirror's starting point and move the mirror along a track until you get to the end of the pencil. You will know the length in terms of the wavelength of the light from the number of full destructive interferences you had.

Answer (score -2):

**The strict answer is: Count the atoms in the direction you want.**

The answer by Dutch Brannigan is 100% correct. I will expand on it for those many that do not understand it.

All the measures we use are based in the atomic properties and counting.
For example the mass unit 1kg is the mass of a definite ensemble of atoms (in Paris prototype) and the mass of each atom is a little part of it.

Only pratical reasons prevent us to choose the usual mass unit ($m_u$) as being the mass of an electron.
The charge unit ($c_u$) is well known: the charge of an electron.
The length unit ($l_u$): we can agree to be the electron radius or the H Bohr radius.
We assume 'c' is constant and the time unit ($t_u$) is a derived one ($c=l_u/t_u$).

In fact when we measure distances we are counting time units.

It is now clear that we measure with atoms (like the ones we see around in the local universe - here and now - the 'regular-size world' in the question.

All the laws of physics are relations about the atomic properties and they are the same laws WHATEVER the actual 'size' of the atoms (mass, charge, Length, time). No law exists able to make a distinction between the atoms of now and the ones in the past.
No one can show with an experiment that the atoms are not changing as time goes by, because to make a measure one have to compare at the same instant the ones of now with their past version that are not available now.

**Without a law and without an experiment it is improper to a physicist, and anyone,  pretend that the atoms are not evolving. The consensus that the 'space expands', without any cause, assumes - it is an hidden axiom - that the atom is not a varying entity - without any kind of evidence.**
To the extraordinary claim 'the space is expanding' an extraordinary demonstration is mandatory. It is the amount of space that is expanding or  only 'the measure of it' with a shorter and shorter atom ?

I maintain with a mathematical proof ([A self-similar model of the Universe unveils the nature of dark energy](http://vixra.org/pdf/1107.0016v1.pdf)) that the atoms are evolving, contrary to the consensus, as seen in the redshifted radiation from the past emited by larger atoms.

An exercise on measure and units: 
suppose that inside the box we have a sample of radioactive Radon and we have a special eye to detect the radiation. If we use it as a clock unit - we can't know that the $t_u$ is decaying - and the laws of physics became awkward - think about the planets motion as they  appear to be approaching us and speeding up - a longer trajectory in each $t_u$.

Using the scientific method one can never discover a new paradigm but one should used it to show that I'm claimning a falsehood. Give it a try.